# nginx not listening on port 443 ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, certbot

I installed Certbot on Google cloud ubuntu server with nginx webserver but nginx does not listen on port 443.

When I type this command

```
netstat -lpn |grep :80
```

I get that tcp listening, but when I type

```
netstat -lpn |grep :443
```

I get nothing.

I'm newbie with Ubuntu and I don't  know what is the problem . Please help, thanks.

Comment: You would probably get a better response on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Check the /etc/nginx folder for config files.  Don't know anything about Google cloud, but I had to install a SSL certificate on my Unbuntu server and setup the certificate chain in the nginx config file, and add a `server` section so nginx would listen on port 443.

Answer (score 0):

Just try `service nginx status`, I'd suppose that nginx isnt running. From there you can start figuring out whats wrong by looking at the logs, i.e. with `journalctl | grep nginx` or at the files in /var/log